# csv file import into mysql with php line return

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

I have an Excel spreadsheet that I saved as a csv file. I have a php script that I'm using to import the csv into a mysql database. I tried to import it and it would get half way through and fail, after a lot of trial and error I have discovered that sometimes there is a problem with line returns but I don't know why. For example, if you look a the lines below (fig 1.), it will run the import ok, over say 20 lines, get to the lines below and error, if I remove a line return (fig 2.), so 2 lines become one line and then add a line return in the same place (fig 3.) and run the import again it works.

fig 1.

```
C10940,Design CLOSED,BRAN B,D4072/2,IN000773,IN000773,2003-06-18,GAG,VG232-232AULP,10
C12261,Newton,CHARLTON G,G4377,IN000908,IN000908,2003-06-18,GAG,VK230-110,31
C12261,Newton,CHARLTON G,G4377,IN000908,IN000908,2003-06-18,GAG,EB211-130,39
```

fig 2.

```
C10940,Design CLOSED,BRAN B,D4072/2,IN000773,IN000773,2003-06-18,GAG,VG232-232AULP,10C12261,Newton,CHARLTON G,G4377,IN000908,IN000908,2003-06-18,GAG,VK230-110,31
C12261,Newton,CHARLTON G,G4377,IN000908,IN000908,2003-06-18,GAG,EB211-130,39
```

fig 3.

```
C10940,Design CLOSED,BRAN B,D4072/2,IN000773,IN000773,2003-06-18,GAG,VG232-232AULP,10
C12261,Newton,CHARLTON G,G4377,IN000908,IN000908,2003-06-18,GAG,VK230-110,31
C12261,Newton,CHARLTON G,G4377,IN000908,IN000908,2003-06-18,GAG,EB211-130,39
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to simply look into MySQL's native [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html#id780182)

e.g.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE /path/to/example.csv
INTO TABLE example_table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```